# How can I compress my FBX file further below 5MB?

Tags: javascript, compression, 3dsmax, gltf

I have an `.fbx` file that takes 58.8MB

After converting it to a `.glb` using draco compression with this package:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/FBX2glTF/tree/master/npm

The file now takes 28.4MB

Ideally, I would need to get the file below 5MB.

How can I achieve that ?

I am using 3DS Max.

---

The character used to take the whole screen on load, now here is what I see after converting the `.fbx` to `.glTF`, reducing the size of the textures from `2048x2048` to `1024x1024` and converting them to `.jpg`  :

[image]

Comment: I don't think a >90% compression ratio is realistic, even for the best compression algorithms, given 3D mesh input data.  Your best bet may be to reduce the amount of incoming data, by removing fine-grained detail.  Some packages call this "decimating" the mesh.  It may also be possible to convert high-poly detail to baked normal maps on a low-poly mesh.

Comment: @emackey Ultimately, I would like to load the model inside three.js to let my users play with it. 5MB is already a lot for most internet connections. I agree that >90% compression is most likely unrealistic, I should have written something to the tune of "the smallest size possible". Do you think it would be possible to gzip  a gltf file and unzip it on the client ? What size gains could I get from that in your opinion ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what portion of your file size is geometry, and what portion is textures. Try exporting to `.gltf` instead of `.glb` to see those separately. Or if you can share the file, that's also helpful.

Comment: Sometimes a lot of the file size comes from textures.  If you have PNG textures and can take a small quality reduction, convert them to JPG for smaller sizes.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy The .gltf is 91KB. All the rest of the 28.4MB is textures...

Comment: In that case you'll need to resize or further compress the images using the usual image compression tools. This can be done without editing the glTF file.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I did that. Loaded the gltf file and now my character seems to have been scaled 1000 times smaller ? I don't understand what happened.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Edited question with screenshot of current situation. No errors in console.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Would you know how to scale it up ?

Comment: I assume this is three.js? See the three.js docs, you can scale things with `object.scale.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 )` or similar.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy That's the thing. I can't. I tried doing gltf.asset.scale.set(1000,1000,1000), it tells mes scale is undefined.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Regardless, this question has essentially been answered now (i.e.: convert to gltf and compress textures, etc...). Only remains for someone to formally do so. In the meantime, I opened a new question for the new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785250/after-converting-my-fbx-file-to-a-gltf-the-model-is-incredibly-small-why with my code, hopefully it is  a bit clearer that way

Comment: @DonMcCurdy So, could you please formally answer this question so I can accept your answer and then we can move to the other issue ? You were the one who suggested exporting to .gltf instead of .glb to see how much space the textures were taking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the filesize of a model you’ll first need to know why it is the size it is. Often this is textures, mesh geometry, or animation data. If you export to `.gltf` instead of the binary `.glb` you should see textures in separate files, and geometry and animations (if any) in a `.bin` file.

To reduce the size of textures, you’ll want to use traditional image optimization tools and shouldn’t need to edit the glTF file at all.

To reduce mesh complexity, use a modeling tool (e.g. “Decimate” in Blender), or compress the glTF file using Draco (as you’ve done here). Reducing the size of animation is a more advanced topic.

Comment: I would welcome your input on this question if you have any: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773583/trying-to-get-the-point-of-intersection-of-a-raycaster