# Trying to get the point of intersection of a raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

**QUESTION:**

I load frontObject onto the scene. I get the centre of said object.

Then I move beyond the object by setting a new point that reuses all the object's centre coordinates except the Z axis (the z coordinate becomes 100), so that I can trace a raycaster from the outside of the character (frontObject) towards it and get the intersection point on the back of the character so that I may place a shield on that point.

Sadly, I get the following output:

[image]

---

**CODE:**

```
let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(frontObject);
            let sphere = box.getBoundingSphere();
            let centerPoint = sphere.center;

            backObject.position.set(0,132,-15);

            console.log("CENTER POINT X: "+centerPoint.x);
            console.log("CENTER POINT Y: "+centerPoint.y);
            console.log("CENTER POINT Z: "+centerPoint.z);

            centerPoint.z = 100;

            var newCoordinate = shootRay(centerPoint, frontObject);

            console.log("NEW POINT X: "+newCoordinate.x);
            console.log("NEW POINT Y: "+newCoordinate.y);
            console.log("NEW POINT Z: "+newCoordinate.z);

function shootRay(center, frontObject) {

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
raycaster.ray.direction.copy( direction );
raycaster.ray.origin.copy( center);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(frontObject);
console.log("GO");
if (intersects) {
    var point  = intersects.point;
    console.log("POINT:"+point);
    return point;

}
```

}

---

**EDIT:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Username100/y54kpe1h/66/

Comment: If you want to find intersection with a single object, then use `.intersectObject(frontObject)` method. If you use `.intersectObjects()` method, then put `frontObject` into an array, thus it would be like that `.intersectObjects([frontObject])`.

Comment: @prisoner849 Sadly, I still get the error :/

Comment: @prisoner849 I added a jsfiddle to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat buggy. You'll want to read and address the warnings that you posted.

For var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(frontObject); frontObject needs to be an Array like [frontObject] or you need to use the singular intersectObject.

I also recommend using a debugger like the one built in to chrome to put a break point, instead of console.log('POINT , and then seeing what you're getting back from the raycast.

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: (for reference, manthrax edited the fiddle with a solution, here: https://jsfiddle.net/manthrax/8evurmyx/43/ )