# After converting my FBX file to a .gltf, the model is incredibly small, why?

Tags: javascript, three.js, scale, fbx, gltf

**QUESTION:**

After converting my FBX file to a .gltf, the model is incredibly small, why ?

I tried scaling the model with `frontObject.scale.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 );` but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

Furthermore, in

```
function ( xhr ) {
                    progressBar.style.display = "block";
                    progressBar.style.width = ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '%';
                    loadingText.innerHTML = 'Loading... '+xhr.loaded+"/"+xhr.total;
                    // For some reason, xhr.total = 0, so I can't use it
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        frontObject.scale.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
                    }, 3000);
                },
```

xhr.total is always equal to 0 and xhr.loaded is equal to an absurdly large number.

All I did was convert my file from .fbx to .gltf and change the size of the textures from 2048x2048 to 1024x1024.

Here is a screenshot of what I am now seeing:

[image]

Before, the model would take the whole vertical height.

---

**CODE:**

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats, controls;
var camera, scene, renderer, light;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var frontObject;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 100, 200, 300 );
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    controls.target.set( 0, 100, 0 );
    controls.update();

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

    light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
    light.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
    scene.add( light );

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
    light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
    scene.add( light );

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 0, -50 );
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
    light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
    scene.add( light );

    // scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );

    // ground
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( mesh );

    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
    grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
    grid.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add( grid );

    load();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

    function load() {

        // Instantiate a loader
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

        // Optional: Provide a DRACOLoader instance to decode compressed mesh data
        THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath( '../path/' );
        THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderConfig( { type: 'js' } );
        loader.setDRACOLoader( new THREE.DRACOLoader() );

        // Load a glTF resource
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            '../path/file.gltf',
            // called when the resource is loaded
            function ( gltf ) {

                scene.add( gltf.scene );

                gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
                gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
                gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
                gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
                gltf.asset; // Object
                frontObject = gltf.asset;

            },
            // called while loading is progressing
            function ( xhr ) {
                progressBar.style.display = "block";
                progressBar.style.width = ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '%';
                loadingText.innerHTML = 'Loading... '+xhr.loaded+"/"+xhr.total;
                // For some reason, xhr.total = 0, so I can't use it
                setTimeout(function () {
                    frontObject.scale.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
                }, 3000);
            },
            // called when loading has errors
            function ( error ) {

                console.log( 'An error happened: '+error );

            }
        );
    }


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if ( mixers.length > 0 ) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {

            mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() );

        }

    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

---

**FIDDLE**:

https://jsfiddle.net/Username100/y54kpe1h/64 
I was able to load the model at the correct size ! But it seems that the default loading manager was incorrectly indicating that everything had loaded, how could that be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes in GLTF files the final size of the object is dictated by parent nodes that apply transforms.

In your code, i'm not sure that

```
  gltf.asset; // Object
  frontObject = gltf.asset;
```

is really your object.

The real object is a child of the `gltf.scene` and can be found using `gltf.scene.traverse` or `.getObjectByName(`

I fixed up your raycasting thing:

https://jsfiddle.net/manthrax/8evurmyx/44/

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed ? I tried : gltf.scene.traverse( function( node ) {

                if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
                 
  
                        frontObject = node;
          
                }

            });

Comment: What should I try exactly ?

Comment: Did that give you a node you could then do .scale.set( on?


You could also try just frontObject = gltf.scene?

As far as the scaling disparity you're seeing, I'm not sure why that is happening. What did you use to do the conversion? There might be some default scaling built in to that...

Comment: As far as tracking the load goes.. there is a separate mechanism in three, called the THREE.LoadingManager... that is created by default or can be created by you...

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager

Comment: I used this for converting from fbx to gltf: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbx2gltf, concerning the default manager, that was what I was using before using the xhr check (which was in the official three.js docs for the gltf loader). So switching back to my old code to check when the assets are loaded I suppose :/ Finally, about the node: I get the a similar error to the one I got before: "cannot read property scale of undefined."

Comment: Is that with setting frontObject = gltf.scene?   that gltf object returned by the loader isn't composed of entirely completed three objects.. it looks like some intermediate data structures that are exposed. For instance gltf.asset. But the stuff from gltf.scene on down should be real THREE objects. If you can't get it to work, Either post a working codepen/fiddle or You can find me here as @thrax: https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Username100/y54kpe1h/62/ I am not sure if the avocado.gtlf I use in the fiddle as an example for my code is actually loading though

Comment: I was able to load the model ! But it seems that the default loading manager was incorrectly indicating that everything had loaded, how could that be ? jsfiddle.net/Username100/y54kpe1h/64

Comment: Loading manager fires early due to a bug. The onLoad method of the loader itself should be fine. See: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14256

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I tried the following and the object had not been loaded when onload was called: `THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onLoad = function() {
    console.log( '-----------------  Loading complete! --------------------')
    frontObject.scale.set(45,45,45);
}`

Comment: Right, that's the bug reported above. The only reliable indicator currently is the onLoad argument to the _loader_, which is `loader.load( url, function (gltf) { console.log(gltf.scene); } )`.